# SPP android/eclipse server, giving back socket closed error?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, sockets, bluetooth

I am trying to run a simple spp server with android and eclipse and it doesn't seem to be connecting is there competition for the UUID or? Also I am using the MAC address of my computer is that correct?

ConnectTest Code on android

Readout:

```
...In onCreate()...
...Bluetooth is enabled...
...In onStart()...
...In onResume...
...Attempting client connect...
...Sending Message to server...
```

Popup:

```
In onResume() and an exception occured during write: socket closed.
```

Eclipse sppserver code

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

import javax.bluetooth.*;
import javax.microedition.io.*;

/**
* Class that implements an SPP Server which accepts single line of
* message from an SPP client and sends a single line of response to the client.
*/
public class SimpleSPPServer {

    //start server
    private void startServer() throws IOException{

        //Create a UUID for SPP
        UUID uuid = new UUID("1101", true);
        //Create the servicve url
        String connectionString = "btspp://localhost:" + uuid +";name=Sample SPP Server";

        //open server url
        StreamConnectionNotifier streamConnNotifier = (StreamConnectionNotifier)Connector.open( connectionString );

        //Wait for client connection
        System.out.println("\nServer Started. Waiting for clients to connect...");
        StreamConnection connection=streamConnNotifier.acceptAndOpen();

        RemoteDevice dev = RemoteDevice.getRemoteDevice(connection);
        System.out.println("Remote device address: "+dev.getBluetoothAddress());
        System.out.println("Remote device name: "+dev.getFriendlyName(true));

        //read string from spp client
        InputStream inStream=connection.openInputStream();
        BufferedReader bReader=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inStream));
        String lineRead=bReader.readLine();
        System.out.println(lineRead);

        //send response to spp client
        OutputStream outStream=connection.openOutputStream();
        PrintWriter pWriter=new PrintWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(outStream));
        pWriter.write("Response String from SPP Server\r\n");
        pWriter.flush();

        pWriter.close();

        streamConnNotifier.close();

    }


    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        //display local device address and name
        LocalDevice localDevice = LocalDevice.getLocalDevice();
        System.out.println("Address: "+localDevice.getBluetoothAddress());
        System.out.println("Name: "+localDevice.getFriendlyName());

        SimpleSPPServer sampleSPPServer=new SimpleSPPServer();
        sampleSPPServer.startServer();

    }
}
```

readout:

```
Address: A45E60EB3CE8
Name: DESKTOP-QD8I9B1

Server Started. Waiting for clients to connect...
```